# Zero KL-divergence $\Rightarrow$ same distribution?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I am looking at [relative entropy=KL-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) and trying to prove, at least in case of probability mass functions $q,\,p$ with possible states $x\in A$ that if:

$$
D(p \,\lVert\,q)=\sum_{x\in A}p\left(x\right)\,\log\left[\frac{p\left(x\right)}{q\left(x\right)}\right] = 0
$$

then $p\left(x\right)=q\left(x\right)\: \forall x \in A$.

I can see that the converse is true, and my book [Cover, Thomas *Elements of Information Theory*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Elements-Information-Theory-Telecommunications-Processing/dp/0471241954) does state that the above result is also valid, but the proof there is, in my opinion, incomplete. The authors use concavity of $\log$ to prove that $D(p \,\lVert\,q)>0$ (happy there). And then state, that the only way to have equality, as opposed to inequality, is to have $,\log\left[\frac{p\left(x\right)}{q\left(x\right)}\right]$ being not strictly concave. Sort of ok with that (not too happy), but then the authors state that the only way to get that is to have $\left[\frac{p\left(x\right)}{q\left(x\right)}\right]=const$. I am not sure how to make that last jump.

Can anyone help? Or suggest an alternative proof? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The only way to have equality is to have $\log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ being not strictly concave" is a weird way to say something here, so you may have misread the proof, or it may be badly worded. However, the idea *is* to figure out the equality case of the inequality we used to prove that KL-divergence is nonnegative.

To begin with, here's a proof that KL-divergence is nonnegative, which is probably essentially the same as the one you read. Let $f(x) = -\log x = \log \frac1x$; this is a strictly convex function on the positive reals. Then by Jensen's inequality
$$
   D(p\,\|\,q) = \sum_{x \in A} p(x) f\left(\frac{q(x)}{p(x)}\right) \ge f\left(\sum_{x \in A} p(x) \frac{q(x)}{p(x)}\right) = f(1) = 0.
$$
For a strictly convex function like $f(x)$, **assuming that the weights $p(x)$ are all positive**, equality holds if and only if the inputs to $f$ are all equal, which directly implies $\frac{q(x)}{p(x)}$ is constant and therefore $p(x)=q(x)$ for all $x$.

We have to be careful if $p(x)=0$ for some inputs $x$. Such values of $x$ are defined to contribute nothing to the KL-divergence, so essentially we have a sum over a different set $A' = \{x \in A : p(x) > 0\}$. Then on the right-hand side of the inequality, we get
$$
    f\left(\sum_{x \in A'} p(x) \frac{q(x)}{p(x)}\right) = f\left(\sum_{x \in A'} q(x)\right).
$$
But now, if the sum over $A'$ is some probability $q<1$, then $f(q) > 0$, and we conclude $D(p\,\|\,q) > 0$. So the sum of $q(x)$ over $A'$ should be $1$. We conclude that when the KL-divergence is $0$, $p(x)=0 \implies q(x)=0$ for all $x \in A$. In order for the KL-divergence to even be defined, $q(x)=0 \implies p(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$. So we can throw away any values where $p(x)=q(x)=0$, and now we're back in the simple case, where all the weights in Jensen's inequality are positive.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can fix this in my head by saying that strict convexity means
$$\lambda f\left(x_1\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)f\left(x_2\right)>f\left(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2\right),\: \forall x_1\neq x_2,\,\lambda\in \left(0,\,1\right)
$$
Therefore equality for a strictly convex function implies that one of the conditions is violated, and since the probabilities are not zero or one, the $x_{\dots}$ s must be equal

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to think about it.